# NSArray as two dimensional array

Tags: iphone, 2d, nsarray, filtering

Can anybody suggest which is the best way for using NSArray as two-dimensional array to store data for filtering data based on field.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create an 1. array of arrays, 2. array of dictionaries, 3. array of custom class objects..

In any case you will have to do almost equal amount of work for filtering based on field..

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't provide any context for your question, is there a reason why you aren't using a 2-dimensional C array to store data? (You can use C primitives, types and structs in Objective-C just fine.) Is there a reason why you *need* to use `NSArray`? (Is it the right tool for the job?)

Comment: my requirement is following i am storing the value in nsarray and i have to remove the duplicate dates.i mean exactly like this (14/12/2010,paid,15/12/2010,pending,15/12/2010,pending,16/12/2010,paid) should be (14/12/2010,paid,15/12/2010,pending,16/12/2010,paid)